# Swift: Animating Constraints on UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, animation, autolayout

There are several answered questions out there similar if not the same as mine, however, none of them seem to solve my dilemma. I have an `UIImageView` that I move across the screen with the `UILongPressGesture` that I move by changing the horizontal and vertical `constraints`. If this `image` does not go a certain distance, I want it to animate back to its original position. I am using the following is an example of the code I am using to try and do this:

```
if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed {

    image1ConstraintX.constant = imageConstX + (translation.x - location.x)
    image1ConstraintY.constant = imageConstY + (translation.y - location.y)

} else if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {

    var xPosition = self.image1.frame.origin.x + image1.frame.width/2
    var yPosition = self.image1.frame.origin.y + image1.frame.width/2
    imageConstX = image1ConstraintX.constant
    imageConstY = image1ConstraintY.constant

    if xPosition < 215 && yPosition < 210 {
        self.image1ConstraintX.constant = 13
        self.image1ConstraintY.constant = 17
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.3, delay: 0.0, options: nil, animations: {
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

                    }, completion: nil)
            }
```

`location.x` and `location.y` are defined elsewhere as the location the user clicks

`translation.x` and `translation.y` are defined as the location the user is in the superview

Needless to say, everything works when panning the `image`. It drags, and then stops when the gesture ends. The problem is that if the user doesn't drag the `image` past a certain location, I want the `image` to animate back to its original location and instead of a smooth transition, it is immediately going to its original position and not animating at all. Based on the other answers to similar questions I am setting the constraints and then calling `layoutIfNeeded` in the `animateWithDuration`.

Is there something with `autolayout` I am missing?

What would I have to change to get the `image` to animate back to its original position?

Comment: sorry about the wrong answer I did a quick research and some test here and I have it working, have a look in my answer again I edit it for you.

Comment: Your updated answer should work, however, for some reason it seems like anytime a `constraint` is changed the `UIImageView` position is updated outside of the `animation`. @matt answer below is working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tested this, but in these situations my first impulse is always to try stepping out with a delay to the main thread. So, first, paste into your file (after the `import` but before everything else) the `delay` utility that I give [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24318861/341994). Now wrap your final case in a very short delay:

```
if xPosition < 215 && yPosition < 210 {
    delay(0.1) {
        self.image1ConstraintX.constant = 13
        self.image1ConstraintY.constant = 17
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.3, delay: 0.0, options: nil, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

If that doesn't solve it, then my next course of action would be to think about these lines:

```
imageConstX = image1ConstraintX.constant
imageConstY = image1ConstraintY.constant
```

Those are not local variables, so what are they? Maybe setting them is having a side effect that you are not taking into account.

Comment: Yes those are variables I set when the view loads and stores the original X and Y `constraints`. I then update those once the `gesture` ends.

Comment: Did you try what I said?

Comment: Just tried it. It worked! terrific. Any idea what's going on under the hood?